# Django models design

Tags: python, sql, django

I am working on a quiz app on Django and have the following models - User, Test, Question and Answer. The Test model acts as a wrapper for the Questions model. This is what my models looks like at present -

models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    def id_count():
        current_count = Test.objects.count()
        current_count += 1
        return current_count
    test_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=id_count,primary_key=True)
    test_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Question(models.Model):
    def id_count():
        current_count = Question.objects.count()
        current_count += 1
        return current_count
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_id = 
    models.PositiveIntegerField(default=id_count,primary_key=True) 
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    option_one = models.CharField(max_length=12,default="Always")
    option_two = models.CharField(max_length=12,default="Never")

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customuser = 
           models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, 
           null=True)
    original_answer_score = 
            models.IntegerField(default=-1)
```

The current models basically allow every user to answer the same question multiple times. How can I design my models to allow every user to answer one question only once? Thanks.

---

Editing to add the respective view:

```
class AnswerFormView(SingleObjectMixin, generic.FormView):
template_name = 'tests/question_detail.html'
form_class = forms.AnswerForm
model = models.Answer

def get_success_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
    return reverse('tests:question_detail', args=(self.kwargs['pk'],))

def form_valid(self, form):
    answer = models.Answer.objects.create(
            question=models.Question.objects.get(question_id=self.kwargs['pk']),
            customuser=self.request.user,
            original_answer_score=form.cleaned_data['original_answer_score']
    )       
    return super(AnswerFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make customer and question a compound index in the Answer table.

Something like:

```
class Answer(...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ( 'customuser', 'question' )
    ...
```

Just put the right field names in that tuple and the uniqueness will be enforced by the database.

More info:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. This works for me at the Admin level, however, my FormView on submitting, still accepts answers that are not unique for the user and question. Edited my question to include that particular CBV. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code for you **Answer** model.

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customuser = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    original_answer_score = models.IntegerField(default=-1, editable=False)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = **('question', 'customuser')**
        ordering = ('question')
```

To answer one question only once you will need to add **editable=False** in your field so that it cannot be edited once entered.

To make the combination of quetion and customuser you will need to add **unique_together** in you Meta class of Model.